# Azure SGX support

Tags: linux, azure, cloud, sgx, confidential

I'm trying to use SGX on Windows Azure as shown in this article [Introduction to Azure Confidential Computation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-confidential-computing/). But I think SGX it is no longer supported by Azure. Is there any other way to run SGX applications on cloud rather than Azure?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it (yet) but Azure now has a Confidential Computing service. They have a "DC" VM that supposedly offers SGX support. I haven't found much info about it though.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/confidential-compute/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [IBM Cloud](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2018/05/data-use-protection-ibm-cloud-using-intel-sgx/), seems it's now available on their VMs.

Answer (score 1):

I registered with the above link. SGX is available with ACC (Azure Confidential Computing) only in EAST US and WEST EUROPE. It is only supported on DC* instances (I have a DC2 with 2 vCPUs and 8GB memory, 32GB disk. It is runing on Ubuntu 18 LTS (Bionic). The CPU is a E-2176G CPU with SGX1, but no SGX2.

However, my application needs `/dev/isgx` but my ACC instance only has `/dev/sgx`, which is not compatible with `/dev/isgx`, so it does not work for me (unless I figure out why I have one and not the other.

Edit: The solution is to first uninstall the `/dev/sgx` driver with the `uninstall.sh` script, which may be under `/opt/intel/` somewhere. Uninstall the driver before even thinking of downloading and unpacking the `/dev/isgx` driver (so it will not be overwritten).

An additional clarification:

- `/dev/sgx` (kernel module `intel_sgx`) is the DCAP driver. It is installed if you select "Open Enclave" when you create an ACC instance.
- `/dev/isgx` (kernel module `isgx`) is the non-DCAP driver that uses IAS. If you want this, deselect "Open Enclave" when creating your ACC instance and manually install the non-DCAP Intel SGX driver from Intel.

More details on Azure's ACC and SGX from a blog by Dan Zimmerman:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/get-started-with-azure-confidential-computing